# Finding a formula for a differential function with two variables

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that $f$ is a differentiable function of a single variable and $F(x,y)$ is defined by $F(x,y) = f(x^2 - y)$.

Given that $F(0,y) = \sin(y)$ for all $y$, find a formula for $F(x,y)$.

---

Would someone be able to show me how to do this question?

Comment: You can deduce that $f(x)=-\sin x$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Why does f(x) = -sin(x)?

Answer (score 2):

$$F(0,y) = \sin(y)=f(-y) \Rightarrow f(x)=-\sin x \Rightarrow F(x,y)=-\sin(x^2-y)$$

Comment: Thanks for this, but why does f(x) = -sinx?

Comment: @comp_questions. In first step we obtain $\sin(y)=f(-y)$, then put $y=-x$.

Comment: Why is it -sin(x^2 - y) instead of -sin(x - y), since f(x) = -sin(x) and not -sin(x^2)?

Comment: @comp_questions. After we know that $f(t)=-\sin t$, we come back to definition of $F(x,y)= f(x^2 - y)$ and use formula obtained for $f$. Just denote $t=x^2 - y$.

Answer (score 2):

Since
$$
F(x, y) = f\left( x^2-y \right)
$$
and since
$$
F(0, y) = \sin (y) 
$$
we obtain
$$
f\left( 0^2 - y \right) = f(-y) = \sin (y),
$$
which implies
$$
f(y) = f\big( - (-y) \big) = \sin (-y) = - \sin y \ \mbox{ for all } y. 
$$
Hence we have
$$
F(x, y) = f\left( x^2 - y \right) = - \sin \left( x^2 - y \right). 
$$

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Why does $f(x) = -\sin(x)$?

---

Because you have :
$$F(0,y)=\sin y$$
And also
$$F(x,y)=f(x^2-y)$$
$$F(0,y)=f(0^2-y)=f(-y)=\sin y $$
So that
$$f(y)=\sin (-y)=-\sin y$$
Finally you can deduce easily $F(c,y)$:
$$F(x,y)=f(x^2-y)=-\sin (x^2-y)$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
F(x,y)
= f(x^2-y)
= f(0^2-(y-x^2))
= F(0, y-x^2)
= \sin(y-x^2).
$$